# ошибка SQL Studio ( hresult: 0x80131040) запрос

Tags: sql-server

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Добрый день, такая картинка возникает в SQL Management Studio 17 при создании запроса к БД. Прошу помощи, спасибо.

Comment: HRESULT: 0x80131040: The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference - Нарушение версионности. Означает что сборка библиотеки на которую ссылается ваше приложение не совпадает с той, которое предусмотрено студией. Проверяйте библиотеки.

Comment: А где задается сборка библиотеки?

Comment: на будущее `Alt+PrScr` копирует в буфер скрин активного окна, а `ctrl+C` текст сообщения

Answer (score 0):

Решилось - просто поставьте Service Pack для Sql Management Studio 2016 и NetFrameWork 4.6.2